# Find value closest to zero in each column of a data frame - R

Tags: r, loops, apply

I have a data frame with a few hundred columns, each with numerical data.

For each column I want to identify the value of the cell with the value closest to zero, without being a positive number.

e.g.

```
X = c(-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8,-9,-10)
Y = c(5,4,3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4)
Z = c(-11,-12,-13,-14,-15,-16,-17,-18,-19,-20)

df <- data.frame(X, Y, Z)
```

I would like some function (fun) to return this vector:

```
fun(df)

[1] -1 0 -11
```

I thought I could use apply functions, or maybe even a loop, or pipes?

Comment: Why pipes though?

Comment: The Q asks _to identify the position_ but your `fun(df)` returns the value. What is your objective, please?

Comment: Edit, apologies, poor english, I meant "identify the value" not "identify the position"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP asked for

> the cell with the value closest to zero, without being a positive number

(as pointed out by @Heroka), returning a vector of values as expected result.

This can be achieved using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) max(x[x<=0])))]

  X Y   Z
 -1 0 -11
```

### Explanations

- `setDT(df)` coerces the data.frame `df` to data.table *by reference*, i.e., without copying.
- for each column, the maximum value which is not positive is returned.
- `unlist()` coerces the resulting data.table to a (named) vector.

Answer (score 13):

We loop over the columns (`sapply(...)`), get the absolute, find the index of the minimum value with `which.min` and subset the value of the column.

```
unname(sapply(df, function(x) x[which.min(abs(x))]))
#[1]  -1   0 -11
```

Comment: To get "value closest to zero, without being a positive number.", whouldn't you need `min(x[x<=0])`?

Comment: @Heroka: You need `max(x[x<=0])`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it lead me to the correct answer for my particular instance in the end, but unfortunately returned some positive numbers on my full dataset, as @Heroka said, `max(x[x<=0])` works.

Comment: @JohnGodlee  No problem.  I coded by the example you posted

Comment: Out of interest, do you know how I would find the position (column and rownumber) of those values?

Comment: @JohnGodlee  perhaps `library(matrixStats); colMaxs(replace(as.matrix(df), df > 0 , NA), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  -1   0 -11`

Comment: @JohnGodlee For finding the row/column indexes `which(df==rep(colMaxs(replace(as.matrix(df), df > 0 , NA), na.rm = TRUE), each = nrow(df)), arr.ind=TRUE)`

Comment: @JohnGodlee or another option is `stack(setNames(lapply(df, function(x) {x1 <- NA^(x > 0)* x; which(x1==max(x1, na.rm=TRUE))}), seq_along(df)))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative using `mapply` and `sapply`. It is probably less efficient than akrun's answer as it creates at least one extra copy of the data.frame.

```
mapply("[", df, sapply(df*df, which.min), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
[1]  -1   0 -11
```

`sapply(df*df, which.min)` will find the indices of the minimum values. These are fed to `mapply` with the data.frame to produce the subsetting.